# How can I add a padding/gap between my cards in responsive bootstrap rows on smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am new to this so even the dumbest thing would be welcome.

[Here there is ample padding as defined in bootstrap as padding-right and padding-left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q7ov.png)

[When I make my display smaller one card goes below and there is no space between the two cards.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsiY3.png)

```
           <div class="row">
              <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card illustration-img">
                  <img
                    src="..." alt="...">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">We got some text here</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card illustration-img">
                  <img
                    src="..."
                    class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">We have text here</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                  <img
                    src="..."
                    class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">We have text here</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The HTML is pretty basic. The CSS code

```
.illustration-img{
padding: 0 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add mb-3 class to col-lg-4 class tags. (mb-1...mb-5)

```
<div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-3 ">
```